# How can I build more facilities?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I have built quite a lot. Now I want to build even more...

There is a way to do it? or it is this all space that I have? If I need to do something, I need to demolish them create what I want?

[image: Facilities]

Comment: Related. [What is the perfect base layout?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89098/what-is-the-perfect-base-layout)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you see is what there is - there's no way to expand your available space.

If you've excavated and built on every tile, that's it, that's all the space you have for building things.

Eventually you'll have researched everything and you can get by without the Laboratories, and some of the buildings can be upgraded (like the Power Generators and Satellite Uplinks) but you'll have to remove the existing buildings in order to do this.

At that point, you may want to have a look at an attempt at a ["perfect" base layout](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/89099/13845).

Comment: I was planning to take Spartacus as the correct answer, but your "cheat" using the perfect layout question as a link gives you the title.

Comment: @Michel,hey, I was like a full... what... 15 seconds faster? :P

Comment: I make it 17 ^^

Answer (score 3):

This is all the space you will ever have.  You can consider saving some space by removing the power generators and replacing some of them with elerium generators.  You can do the same with the satellite upliniks and nexus.  Finally, once you are done with all research, you can remove the labs for more workspaces.